# How is ORDER BY used with PARTITION BY

Tags: sql

I am trying to tease out precisely what the ORDER BY clause does in SQL partitioning. I've reviewed other posts, but if any answer this question, I didn't find them.

Consider the following SQL: (T-SQL, but I suppose this will work the same in Postgres?)

```
select
    EmpId
  , ArchiveId
  , max(ArchiveId) over (partition by EmpId order by EmpId asc) as Max1ArchiveId
  , max(ArchiveId) over (partition by EmpId order by EmpId desc) as Max2ArchiveId
  , max(ArchiveId) over (partition by EmpId order by ArchiveId asc) as Max3ArchiveId
  , max(ArchiveId) over (partition by EmpId order by ArchiveId desc) as Max4ArchiveId
  , max(ArchiveId) over (partition by EmpId) as Max5ArchiveId
from Sales.EmployeeArchive
where
  EmpId = 108724
```

This select statement produces the following dataset:

| EmpId | ArchiveId | Max1ArchiveId | Max2ArchiveId | Max3ArchiveId | Max4ArchiveId | Max5ArchiveId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 108724 | 1988380 | 1988380 | 1988380 | 1988380 | 1988380 | 1988380 |
| 108724 | 1846645 | 1988380 | 1988380 | 1846645 | 1988380 | 1988380 |
| 108724 | 689693 | 1988380 | 1988380 | 689693 | 1988380 | 1988380 |
| 108724 | 221093 | 1988380 | 1988380 | 221093 | 1988380 | 1988380 |
| 108724 | 174430 | 1988380 | 1988380 | 174430 | 1988380 | 1988380 |
| 108724 | 139904 | 1988380 | 1988380 | 139904 | 1988380 | 1988380 |

I get that for the 5th flavor, no ORDER BY has been provided, so (as the documentation states) the "window function will use all rows in partition". Fine.

And I think I understand why the 3rd max "fails" to get the true archive max for this one EmpId value. The T-SQL documentation states that when an ORDER BY is included, RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW is used. So when it's sorted DESC we know the max from the first row, but only on the last row when sorted ASC. Fine.

But why, when I sort by EmpId, do we know the max ArchiveId value, regardless of which way EmpId was sorted? (And yes, I know that the EmpId values are all the same value for each window, so the "sort" does nothing that the naked eye can see.)

I could assume that the entire window for each EmpId is evaluated "as if no ORDER BY phrase had been provided". But an ORDER BY *was* provided.

Or I suppose we could just *assume* that the engine is sorting in both cases by ArchiveId DESC secondarily after the primary EmpId sort. But that seems a stretch. Why DESC? ArchiveId is an identity field that I would have guessed should default to ASC, if anything.

(Please be aware that I have no particular reason to need all of these partition flavors, and some may be nonsensical. This is just an exercise to help me understand what the engine is doing.)

Comment: Adding an order by to min/max/etc window functions makes it non-deterministic. Don't do it.  Order by with window functions is only relevant for running sums, comparing current row to "previous" row, etc.

Comment: It's because of `range between` vs `rows between`. You range extends to all the rows with the same value.